# Map value to DTO which is missing into Entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement DTO mapping after SQL query execution with SQL JOIN:

Query:

```
public List<Businesses> findCompaniesBusinessesById(Integer id) {
    String hql = "SELECT bus FROM " + Businesses.class.getName() + " bus " 
                + " INNER JOIN " + Companies.class.getName() + " comp "
                + " ON comp.id = bus.company_id " 
                + " WHERE bus.business_owner_id = :id "
                + " AND bus.business_owner_type = 'Merchant' "
                + " ORDER BY bus.id ASC";
    TypedQuery<Businesses> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Businesses.class).setParameter("id", id);
    List<Businesses> businesses = query.getResultList();
    return businesses;
}
```

Entity Companies:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Companies implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime created_at;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime updated_at;
    ...
}
```

Entity Businesses:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "businesses")
public class Businesses {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer business_owner_id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String business_owner_type;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer company_id;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime created_at;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime updated_at;
    .......
}
```

**!NOTE!** In Businesses entity we don't have attribute `name` by design.

DTO:

```
public class BusinessesDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    ....... 
}
```

**!NOTE!** In BusinessesDTO we expect `name` by design and we want to map it.

DTO Mapping:

```
@Mapper(config = BaseMapperConfig.class)
public interface BusinessesMapper {

    BusinessesDTO toDTO(Businesses company);
    .....
}
```

Result from the query when I execute it manually:

```
SELECT * FROM  businesses bus   
        INNER JOIN  companies comp
          ON comp.id = bus.company_id 
          WHERE bus.business_owner_id = 1
          AND bus.business_owner_type = 'Merchant' 
          ORDER BY bus.id ASC
```

[image]

As you can see there is a column name.

I tried to use this code to get the mapping:

```
@Autowired
private BusinessesMapper businesses_mapper;

List<BusinessesDTO> list = null;
try {
    list = StreamSupport.stream(merchantService.findCompaniesBusinessesById(id).spliterator(), false)
        .map(businesses_mapper::toDTO)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String joinedList = list.stream()
    .map(BusinessesDTO::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

But for a result I get NULL. For some reason name is not mapped correctly and I can't find why.

*Is it possible not to have `name` attribute into `Businesses` entity and to map a `name` field that exists into the SQL query using DTO.*

From the SQL query picture I get the name properly as you can see above. Can you give me some idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: Are you using Selma mapper?

Comment: No I use mapstruct

Comment: In generale mapper tools is not enought smart, in your case you need something like this `@Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "company.name", target = "name")
    })`

Comment: More details http://javadevcorner.com/mapstruct-custom-mapping-rest-operations/#Role_attribute_to_DTO

Comment: But your query findCompaniesBusinessesById is HQL not SQL. Do you want to use SQL?

Comment: I want to find a solution with HQL. My mistake.

Comment: But you cannot access non mapped columns with HQL